# I think I'll stay here

Tags: riddle

I'm an emperor's son, but with none of his glory.

I have hardcore brothers who are still strong today.

When you hear my full name, you might think I'm unlucky

Or that I am going to fall into decay.

If I do my thing twice, there's not even a story...

I think I'll stay here, where I'm doing okay.

---

*Who am I ?*

---

Hint : added two new lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This riddle overviews the

> rot13 - rotating the alphabet by 13 places - cipher.

I'm an emperor's son, but with none of his glory.

> You are a special case of the (Julius) Caesar cipher, which shifts by 1 to 25.

I have hardcore brothers who are still strong today.

> There are strong encryption ciphers which are difficult to break even with computing power.

When you hear my full name, you might think I'm unlucky, Or that I am going to fall into decay.

> Rot for decay and 13 for unlucky.

If I do my thing twice, there's not even a story...

> This sentence is encoded by two applications of rot13.

I think I'll stay here, where I'm doing okay.

> rot13 is popular on PSE to hide spoilers.

Comment: pbatenghyngvbaf

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> A biscuit

I'm an emperor's son, but with none of his glory.

> Emperor penguin without the emperor is just a [penguin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguin_%28biscuit%29)

I have hardcore brothers who are still strong today.

> ? Crunchy centers or maybe Boasters biscuits (still strong)

If I do my thing twice, there's not even a story...

> Hobnobs - dip them twice in your tea and they don't break

I think I'll stay here, where I'm doing okay.

> ?

Comment: Funny answer, but not at all what I was thinking about :)